# Laravel Auth Redirect Back (Remember Link)

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, redirect

Currently my flow (like many others is as so)...

1.) Add to Basket

2.) View Basket

3.) Click Checkout (Works if logged in- but unlikely as most buyers are guests)

4.) Taken to Login

5.) Click to to register

6.) Register

7.) Redirected to homepage

The redirect to homepage is CORRECT for normal registrations... This is the intended outcome.

But not if you are redirected from another task, for example.
If you have an existing login and you login (after being redirected from the basket because further steps require auth) it will automatically (on Laravel) redirect you back to the basket.

However, when register this involves an extra click from Register>Login the `intended` seems to be lost.

For instance this works fine on my login..

`if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return redirect()->intended('defaultpage');
}`

However on my register (additional click) it is lost, how do i pass the `intended` one more page

I hope this make sense! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried saving it in a session variable? That would be one approach

Comment: I dont think the intended url can be passed along - you can overwrite the postRegistration method and work from there.

Comment: @AngadDubey shame to hear, i dont want all registrations to be push back though. Only those with the intended?